# BeforeGroups method is not executed when running testng tests by maven

Tags: java, maven, testng

I see that the method marked with "@BeforeGroups" is not executed by .

Java test class:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.fail;

@Test(groups = "http")
public class MyIT {

    @Test(groups = "http")
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("test 1 - value from TestServerConfigurator: "
            + TestServerConfigurator.getSomeString());
    }
}
```

in the same package - the class to configure server:

```
public class TestServerConfigurator {
    private static String someString;

    @BeforeGroups(groups = "http")
    public static void init() {
        System.out.println("initializing server...");
        someString = "value set!";
    }

    @AfterGroups(groups = "http")
    public static void after() {
        System.out.println("stopping server...");
    }

    public static String getSomeString() {
        return someString;
    }
}
```

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
           http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.alskor</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mytests</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>http</groups>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

running:

**mvn integration-test**

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:integration-test (default) @ mytests ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running MyIT
test 1 - value from TestServerConfigurator: null
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.218 sec - in MyIT

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Maven Failsafe Plugin – Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html):

> By default, the Failsafe Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - `"**/IT*.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "IT".
> - `"**/*IT.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "IT".
> - `"**/*ITCase.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "ITCase".

As the `TestServerConfigurator` class name does not match any of the default inclusion patterns it is being excluded from your test run.

You can rename `TestServerConfigurator` to something that matches the default patterns (i.e. `ITTestServerConfigurator`, `TestServerConfiguratorIT`, or `TestServerConfiguratorITCase`) or define your own inclusion patterns:

```
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Configurator.java</include>
                </includes>
                <groups>http</groups>
            </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see it works if I replace "configuration" section with this:

```
    <configuration>
        <groups>http</groups>
        <includes>
            <include>*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
```

I thought "includes" section was intended to list tests only and not all classes that should be visible to testng, but apparently that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem.
Add `@Test(groups = "http")` to your `TestServerConfigurator` class

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `ChromeDriver` version as per your system browser.